# Client-side framework for web-app with good audio support

Tags: java, flash, silverlight, web-applications, audio

I'm trying to create a client-side web app that generates music procedurally using some user-input parameters, so I'm looking for a framework (e.g. Flash, Silverlight etc.) that has the capability to play audio **at a specified pitch**. Whether it is playing a WAV/MP3 file, using MIDI output, or just playing beeps doesn't really matter -- I just need something that will enable me to generate arbitrary music client-side.

I've done a bit of searching and it appears that Flash might have the ability to change pitch with the help of a third-part plugin, but I couldn't find anything similar for Silverlight. I can go a try all them out manually if need be, but I thought I'd ask here first just in case anyone had tried something like this before.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Silverlight, but sure as hell you can do it in Flash. Just this week Audiotool has been released:

http://www.audiotool.com/

Don't fool yourself though, that's a state-of-the-art application that requires squeezing every single bit of the Flash Player. You can read about what it takes to build it here:

http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2010/03/06/compiling-actionscript-in-the-enterprise/

Cheers,

Juan